# Getting Service Unavailable for service metrices command in EKS

Tags: kubernetes

I am getting `ServiceUnavailable` error when I try to run `kubectl top nodes` or `kubectl top pods` command in EKS. I am running my cluster in EKS , and I am not finding any solution for this online. If any one have faced this issue in EKS please let me know how we can resolve this issue

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
```

out put of `kubectl get apiservices v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apiregistration.k8s.io/v1","kind":"APIService","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"k8s-app":"metrics-server"},"name":"v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io"},"spec":{"group":"metrics.k8s.io","groupPriorityMinimum":100,"insecureSkipTLSVerify":true,"service":{"name":"metrics-server","namespace":"kube-system"},"version":"v1beta1","versionPriority":100}}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-02-03T08:22:59Z"
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
  resourceVersion: "1373088"
  uid: 2066d4cb-8105-4aea-9678-8303595dc47b
spec:
  group: metrics.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  service:
    name: metrics-server
    namespace: kube-system
    port: 443
  version: v1beta1
  versionPriority: 100
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-02-03T08:22:59Z"
    message: 'failing or missing response from https://10.16.55.204:4443/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1:
      Get "https://10.16.55.204:4443/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1": dial tcp 10.16.55.204:4443:
      i/o timeout'
    reason: FailedDiscoveryCheck
    status: "False"
    type: Available
```

`metrics-server   1/1     1            1           3d22h`

`kubectl describe deployment metrics-server -n kube-system`

```
Name:                   metrics-server
Namespace:              kube-system
CreationTimestamp:      Thu, 03 Feb 2022 09:22:59 +0100
Labels:                 k8s-app=metrics-server
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 2
Selector:               k8s-app=metrics-server
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  0 max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:           k8s-app=metrics-server
  Service Account:  metrics-server
  Containers:
   metrics-server:
    Image:      k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.0
    Port:       4443/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Args:
      --cert-dir=/tmp
      --secure-port=4443
      --kubelet-insecure-tls=true
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
      --kubelet-use-node-status-port
      --metric-resolution=15s
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     200Mi
    Liveness:     http-get https://:https/livez delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get https://:https/readyz delay=20s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /tmp from tmp-dir (rw)
  Volumes:
   tmp-dir:
    Type:               EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:          <unset>
  Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   metrics-server-5dcd6cbcb9 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [components.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml), find and replace 4443 to 443 and do a `kubectl replace -f components.yaml -n kube-system --force`.

Comment: I have added the yaml and deployment output. it is not working for me since metric service installation

Comment: Can you also post the complete output of `kubectl describe deployment metrics-server -n kube-system`

Comment: I have added that to question

Comment: Download the [components.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml), find and replace `4443` to `443` and do a `kubectl replace -f components.yaml -n kube-system --force`

Comment: Great , it did work. Can you tell me how can we troubleshoot such issues in future. how to notice that port was needed to change?